# When does $2f(x)=f(2x)$ imply $mf(x)=f(mx)$?

Tags: analysis

When teaching middle schoolers about proportional relationships, I was struck by simplicity and power of one heuristic:

"If doubling each quantity reliably gets correct answers, then the relationship is proportional."

This works in the context of dollars to total cost, miles per hour at constant speed, etc...

I was wondering under what conditions this actually holds true. In other words, when does

$\forall_{x\in \text{domain}(f)} 2f(x) =f(2x)\rightarrow \forall_{m\in \mathbb{R}}\forall_x mf(x)=f(mx)$. I know uniform continuity is sufficient. I know it doesn't hold when the domain of $f$ is only the national numbers. I am stuck when $f$ is continuous. I know that any contiunous $f$ which would be a counterexample is an extension of some $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ and I know a little bit about how those look like. I am very stuck now, however, and suspect the problem may be beyond what I can do atm.

I don't want an answer, but a hint/encouragement/helpful references.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $f : [1, 2] \to \mathbb{R}$ is any continuous function with $f(2) = 2f(1)$, then we can extend it uniquely to a continuous function $f : (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(2x) = 2f(x)$. You can extend the domain of $f$ to be all of $\mathbb{R}$ if you like, but this extension is not unique (you have the same freedom in constructing a map $(-\infty, 0) \to \mathbb{R}$, and the value at $x = 0$ has to be zero).

On the other hand, if $f(mx) = mf(x)$ for all $m \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f(x) = f(x\times 1) = xf(1)$. Moreover, if $f(x) = kx$ then $f(mx) = mf(x)$ for all $m \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(1) = k$. That is, $f(mx) = mf(x)$ for all $m \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $f(x) = kx$ for some $k$ (and this $k$ will be $f(1)$).

So to construct a counterexample, you just need to start with a continuous function $f : [1, 2] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(2) = 2f(1)$ which is not of the form $f(x) = kx$ (there are many such functions) and extend it as above.

I'm not sure there is any natural condition of the sort you seem to be looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I've produced a graph of the function you imply (using a base of $f(x)=1+(x-1)^2$. It's uniformly continuous on closed bounded intervals, which inspires me to take another look at my original work.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ has a power series you are done because all of the coefficients except possibly the coefficient of $x$ must be zero if you require $f(2x) = 2f(x)$. This is just a simple example of many other functional equations. It is an interesting topic with surprising results. Another example is $f(2x) = 4f(x)$ which has pure quadratic solutions. A much more interesting example is $0 = f(3x)f(x) - f(2x)^2 +  f(x)^2$ which has circular or hyperbolic sine solutions.

Comment: So you are saying that it's true of any function with a power series?

Comment: Yes, that is what I claimed. Try it and see for yourself.